# Problems implementing Euler's Method on a second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to teach myself some numerical methods and having more issues than expected trying to solve $$y'' = -y$$ with initial conditions $y'(0) = 0$ and $y(0) = 1$.

As I understand the problem, based on the information found here [Solve a second order DEQ using Euler's method in MATLAB](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556858/solve-a-second-order-deq-using-eulers-method-in-matlab), I made the substitution $u = y'$ and reduced the problem to the following coupled system:

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
y' = u;\\
u' = -y.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
So in this case, since $y'(0) = 0$, this implies $u=0$ and $y(0) = 1$ implies $u'(0) = -1$. With these initial conditions, I have the vector $[y_{0},u_{0}] = [0,-1]^{T}$. I tried to use a forward Euler method on this system using

\begin{align*}
y_{n+1} = y_{n} + hu_{n}\\
u_{n+1} = u_{n} - hy_{n}
\end{align*}
with $y_{0} = 0$, $u_{0} = -1$ but at this point I am not sure how I can extract the solution to my original differential equation. I am storing my $y_{i}$'s and $u_{i}'s$ in a $2\times n$ matrix where the first row contains $[y_{0},y_{1},y_{2},\dots, y_{n}]$ and the second row contains the same information for $u_{i}$'s in the same manner.

It appears to me, that my matrix should contain the solution to my original differential equation in the first row, but this cannot be the case because the solution to the differential equation is $y(t) = \cos(t)$, and  $\cos(t_{0}) = \cos(0) = 1\neq 0$. Similarly, it cannot be the second row because $\cos(0) = 1 \neq -1$.

If I change the initial condition to $[y_{0},u_{0}]^{T} =[0,1]$ and I take the solution to be the second row corresponding to the $u_{i}$'s, it looks like I get a reasonable answer, but I cannot understand whether this is simply a numerical fluke or if I made a flawed calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting $[y_{0},u_{0}] = [0,-1]$, you make your initial conditions $y(0)=0, u(0)=-1$. They contradict what you've found to be $y(0)=1$ and $u(0)=0$.

Also, you don't need $y'(0)$ and $u'(0)$ as initial conditions for the system of first-order ODEs when you already have $y(0)$ and $u(0)$. The Cauchy problem needs one initial condition per first order ODE.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion can also be put in vector format

$$\begin{bmatrix}y_{n+1}\\u_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}1&h\\-h&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_n\\u_n\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}1&h\\-h&1\end{bmatrix}^{n+1}\begin{bmatrix}y_0\\u_0\end{bmatrix}$$

The iteration matrix corresponds to the matrix representation of the complex number $q=1+ih$ with polar coordinates $q=\sqrt{1+h^2}\,e^{i\arctan h}$, which results in 
$$y_n=Re(q^n)=(1+h^2)^{n/2}\cos(n\arctan h)=(1+h^2)^{n/2}\cos(\tfrac{\arctan h}{h}t_n).$$

So you have not only to expect a growth in magnitude, but also a distortion in the frequency.